How many nazirites are there in the world today?
It is very easy to make a nazirite vow, all that is required is, “he made a decision in his heart to take a nazirite vow and verbally expressed concepts that suggest this intent.” Mishnah Torah, Nazariteship 1:5.
But due to the lack of a Temple, “when a person takes a nazirite vow in the present era, he must observe it forever, because we do not have a Temple where he can go and offer his sacrifices at the conclusion of his nazirite vow.”  Id. 2:20.
So it is logical that there must be many nazirites in the world today. Are there any figures or educated guesses on how many?

What makes you think there are any? Or that we'd know if there were?

Sefer haHinuch notes that making such a wow is discouraged by hachamim.

@shmosel Due to the  easiness of making the vow, and the impossibility of  completing it, I think “zero nazirites” is the least likely scenario.

There is at least one, he was interviewed by Eli Stefansky on his daf yomi podcast, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svvp3EMbOP8&ab_channel=MercazDafYomibyR%27Eliofthe8MinuteDaf

It's a foolish thing to do, so almost no one does it. You can't make the vow by accident, however easy it is to make (and then super difficult to keep.)

1+1 doesn't make it 3. IIRC, some ruled that Nazirus was annulled with the Temple as all Temple-related rites. So how do you deduct from that Rambam that taking vows holds today?

@AlBerko I don't think anyone ever ruled that

@DoubleAA Right, but I've got a general feeling that de facto that excuse is used for all "once upon a time" practices: "Oh, there's no Temple, we don't discuss it".

@AlBerko na that's just you making things up
